# Can Someone explain Swift's Application Binary Stability in simple terms?

Tags: swift

I have tried looking up ABI Stability documentation on swift.org. I did not find it that useful as I am a very novice iOS Developer. I don't even understand what problem are they trying to solve and why is it really important for the maturity of the language?

Comment: ABI is not just related to Swift. I think that if you read a bit further into what ABI means you will have a clearer understanding of what ABI stability means not only for swift but for all languages.

Comment: What else do you need to know? https://swift.org/blog/abi-stability-and-more/